# "Download all attachments" does not work for Hotmail in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, hotmail

I have recently tried both Firefox and Chrome. I use Hotmail. In these browsers, "download all attachments" does not work. What can I do to enable this?

Thanks.

On checking I discovered that this "feature" is not working in Hotmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it working in IE?

If not, the problem probably on the server, so you can't do anything to solve this problem except form report the bug [here](https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?scrx=1).

Comment: Very good. It always worked so I never went back and checked. It works in non of the  browsers.
Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks.

Searching Hotmail help I found that this "feature" is not working right now.

Thanks for the link and your help. +1 plus accept.
Regards